# Gammu on raspberry Zero

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am trying to setup a raspberry zero to collect the temperature from a DS18B20 probe connected to a -20°C fridge of my lab. If a temperature above a certain value is detected, the raspberry should send an email to alert for a a problem. I use a chinese (IEASUN Technology) HSUPA modem with a Qualcom chip. Gammu is used to communicate with the modem. After installing gammu and my script, everything worked as expected. Then, I decided to add a function: upon sending a sms to the raspberry, I wanted that it sent back the temperatures of the connected probes (and I had to install gammu-smsd). This new function is working but my original alert script does not work anymore.
I must emphasise that this is done as an autodidact with minimal knowledge in coding (this will be obvious in the code).
Here are several key information.

When I run my 'Alert' script, now, I have this message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendsmstemp.py", line 11, in <module>
    sm.Init()
gammu.ERR_DEVICEOPENERROR: {'Text': u'Error opening device. Unknown, busy or no permissions.', 'Code': 2, 'Where': 'Init'}`

The code of my 'Alert' script is:

```
import gammu
import sys
    # Create state machine object
    sm = gammu.StateMachine()
    # Read ~/.gammurc
    sm.ReadConfig()
    # Connect to phone
    sm.Init()
import time

while 1:
        tempfile1 = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-031689cf76ff/w1_slave")
        thetext1 = tempfile1.read()
        tempfile1.close()
        tempdata1 = thetext1.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
        temperature1 = float(tempdata1[2:])
        temperature1 = temperature1 / 1000

if temperature1>-10:
      
message1 = {
    'Text': 'Time is:' + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')+'| Temperature Fridge 1 above -10°C!! . If still above the limit, another sms will be sent in 30min',
    'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
    'Number': '+Myphonenumber',
    'Validity': 'Max',
}
sm.SendSMS(message)

#It waits 30min before sending another sms
time.sleep(1800)

Else:

#test the probe every min
time.sleep(60)
```

This code is launched at startup with this sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
sudo python /home/pi/smstemp/sendsmstemp.py
```

The last script that I have added to this raspberry — which required the installation of gammu-smsd package — that has apparently broken the first one is:

```
#!/bin/sh
from=$SMS_1_NUMBER
message=$SMS_1_TEXT


#ThisHost=$(hostname)

# local file to write into
#FILE=$ThisHost"-status.txt"

# local directory to write to file and pick it for upload
#REPERTOIRE="/home/pi/sendsmstemp/"
#echo $REPERTOIRE$FILE

#Read last temperature 
temperature1=$(find /sys/bus/w1/devices/ -name "28-*6ff" -exec cat {}/w1_slave \; | grep "t=" | awk -F "t=" '{print $2/1000}')

#Send message
reply=""
echo "Temp Fridge 1: $temperature1" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$from"
```

Now, my /etc/gammu-smsdrc config file looks like that:

```
    [gammu]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB0
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at
    gammucoding = utf8

    [gammu1]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB1
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at
    gammucoding = utf8

    [gammu2]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB2
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at
    gammucoding = utf8

    [gammu3]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB3
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at
    gammucoding = utf8

    [smsd]
    service = files
    #logfile = syslog
    logfile = /var/spool/gammu/log/gammu-smsdrc.log
    # Change PIN code
    pin = 1234
    RunOnReceive = /home/pi/sendsmstemp/sendinfo.sh
```

My /etc/gammurc config file is the same (except that the last line is not included).

The gamma-detect command returns that:

```
    [gammu]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB0
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at

    [gammu1]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB1
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at

    [gammu2]
    device = /dev/ttyUSB2
    name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
    connection = at


[gammu3]
device = /dev/ttyUSB3
name = Phone on USB serial port Qualcomm__Incorporated Qualcomm_CDMA_Technologies_MSM
connection = at
```

The gammu --identify returns that:

```
  Device               : /dev/ttyUSB1
    Manufacturer         : Qualcomm
    Model                : unknown (+CGMM:HSPA MODEM)
    Firmware             : +CGMR:V1.1
    IMEI                 : 356793034431627
    SIM IMSI             : +CIMI:208150010138412
```

The gammu getsecuritystatus returns that:

```
Nothing to enter.
```

And using this command works as expected (it send a sms):

```
gammu sendsms TEXT 06xxxxxxxx -text "Test"
```

Why my 'Alert' script is not running??? I am lost.

Many many thanks for your help!!

Comment: I have may be an explanation to my issue. It is said here: https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/smsd.html?highlight=script that  "you can not run Gammu and Gammu SMSD at same time on signle device". A solution is provided but I failed to make it work. I have re-installed everything except the gammu-smsd package. I give up...

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comment to my question, I gave up. I have amended and debugged the alert script, for those that might be interested (it works with 2 probes and it is easy to add other probes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
import gammu
import sys

# Create state machine object
sm = gammu.StateMachine()
# Read ~/.gammurc
sm.ReadConfig()
# Connect to phone
sm.Init()

import time


while 1:
    tempfile1 = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-031689cf76ff/w1_slave')
    tempfile2 = open('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-051691e603ff/w1_slave')
    thetext1 = tempfile1.read()
    thetext2 = tempfile2.read()
    tempfile1.close()
    tempfile2.close()
    tempdata1 = thetext1.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
    tempdata2 = thetext2.split("\n")[1].split(" ")[9]
    temperature1 = float(tempdata1[2:])
    temperature2 = float(tempdata2[2:])
    temperature1 = temperature1 / 1000
    temperature2 = temperature2 / 1000

    if int(temperature1) > -10 or int(temperature2) > -10:
        #Tony
        message = {
        'Text': time.strftime('%H:%M') + '\r\nTemperature of a Team 1 Fridge above -10deg' + '\r\nFridge 1=' + str(temperature1) + 'deg\r\nFridge 2=' + str(temperature2) + 'deg\r\nIf still above the limit, another SMS will be sent in 30 min',
        'SMSC': {'Location': 1},
        'Number': '+336XXXXXXXXX',
        'Validity': 'Max',
        }
        sm.SendSMS(message)
        time.sleep(1800)


        #Check every min
        time.sleep(60)
```